# Why am I getting a large horizontal band spreading across my native gel?

Tags: molecular-biology, experimental-design, protein-binding, gel-electrophoresis

On every gel of this type that I've ran so far, I'm getting this large band interfering with my gel analysis no matter how much troubleshooting I've done. This is a Novex Wedgewell 6% Tris-Glycine Gel and in each well I've loaded 10ul of the Novex 2X Native Tris-Glycine Sample Buffer + 10ul of my sample. I ran the gel at 100V for 1hr at 4C. This image is from under a Fluorescein Blot filter.

I've troubleshooted the gel by pre-running it and also trying to load without any 2x loading buffer, but the band has still remained.

[image]